# Compute the remainder of multiplying two long number?

Tags: java, cryptography, repeat

I am writing a code for a crypto method to compute x^d modulo n using Repeated Squaring

```
public static long repeatedSquaring(long x, long d, long n){
        x = x%n;
        boolean dj = d % 2 == 1;
        long c = dj ? x : 1;

        d = d / 2;
        while (d > 0){
            dj = d % 2 == 1;
            x = x * x % n; //Here
            if (dj)
                c = c * x % n; //and here..
            d = d / 2;
        }
        return c;
    }
```

This code work fine when `n` is small. But with `n > sqrt(Long.MAX_VALUE)`it gives an unexpected result.
Because with `x ≈ n`, we can have `x*x > Long.MAX_VALUE` and then the modulo operator give an incorrect value assign to `x` (or `c`).
So, my question is, how we can compute  (A * B) % N (all are `long` type) using only math related method.
 
I don't want to use BigInteger (`BigA.multiply(BigB).remainder(BigN)` or we can use `BigX.modPow(BigD, BigN)` directly for the big problem).
I think that a normal computing will run faster than String computing? Morever with my problem, all temp values are `long` type 'enough'. 
And I wonder that the solution will work fine with the worst case: `A, B, N <≈ Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiplying can be done in log(B) time simliar to exponentiation

if(b is odd) a+multiply(2*a,(b-1)/2) mod N
else multiply(2*a,b/2) mod N

this works till longvalue/2

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_reduction might be more optimum

Comment: Nice answer, is it possible to create Java code for it? I presume this takes into account that Java long is signed?

Comment: this overflows only if a+N-1 overflows so i guess a,n should be less than maxlong/4.
Anyway it's O(maxlong) ,better than sqrt(maxlong).

Answer (score 1):

Really, the short answer is that you need to use `BigInteger`, even if you don't want to. As you've discovered, the approach you're currently taking will overflow the bounds of a `long`; even if you improve the algorithm, you still can't get more than 64 bits into the answer with a `long`.

You say you're using this for crypto; but 64-bit public key crypto is so weak that it is worse than not having it (because it gives a false sense of security). Even 1024 bits is not enough these days for public key, and 64 bits could be cracked more or less instantaneously.

Note that this is not the same as symmetric crypto, where the keys can be much smaller. (But even there, 64 bits is not enough to stop even an amateur hacker.)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808691/rsa-key-length-and-export-limitations), where it was pointed out that 64-bit RSA can be cracked in a fraction of a second... and that was four years ago!